# CSS background images in MVC3

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create style sheet for my MVC3 app.  I'm not sure how to format the background-image:url.

```
background-image:url('../../Content/images/gradient_tile_page_top.png');
```

or

```
background-image:url('~/Content/images/gradient_tile_page_top.png');
```

I've tried both and neither work.  Css seems to be a little trickier with MVC.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you're following the "norm" your main page layout will have something like:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and your other assets (images for example) will either reside directly in the content folder or in an "images" folder under content.

Therefore, in your example:

```
background-image:url('../../Content/images/gradient_tile_page_top.png');
```

becomes

```
background-image:url('images/gradient_tile_page_top.png');
```

Comment: What if I'm not following the "norm" and just want an inline url without css?

Comment: for **multi level folder** try this `background-image: url("themes/base/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png")`