# CSS Background Images in MVC3 - Continuation

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I recently purchased a bootstrap theme that I am attempting to apply to my MVC3 Web App project.

I am having problems getting a background image in social-icons.css to render.

In _Layout.cshtml i have referenced:

```
link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/social-icons.css")" rel="stylesheet"      type="text/css"
```

in the header.

Within social-icons.css:

```
    [class^="social-"],
    [class*="social-"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: .3em;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    background-image: url("img/icons/social-icon-set.png");
    background-position: 40px 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50em;
       -moz-border-radius: 50em;
            border-radius: 50em;
}
```

I have checked both the paths of social-icons.css 
and social-icons-set.png and everything appears on the up and up.

I checked the Q&A here and this did not help me.  [CSS background images in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035999/css-background-images-in-mvc3)

Would like to apologize in advance for any unclear information.

Comment: Hello Farrowdm, and welcome to StackOverflow.
Your question looks good and clear to me, so i hope we can be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the image location wrong.

Here's what you have:

```
background-image: url("img/icons/social-icon-set.png");
```

And as we can see be your screenshot, it's **`social-icons-set`** (**note the extra "s"**):

[image]

Comment: Haha,  I'm sick to my stomach.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @farrowdm Hehe no problems, these things happen to all of us! Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 1):

Any paths in CSS files are always relative to the css file itself.
Is the png located in `Content/img/icons/social-icon-set.png` ?

Because that is where the CSS file and your info suggests it should be.

Comment: Clearly not. (see Mattytomo's answer)